# Visual Studio generated suspicious assembly code when a oneAPI TBB header is present in a PCH

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tbb, precompiled-headers

After building the code shown below in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.7.6 and running it, an exception `std::length_error` is thrown within MS C++ STL implementation. It attempts to create a vector using `size_t( -1 )` as a size parameter.

```
//main.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int foo()
{
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vs(foo() + 1);
    std::cout << vs.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
//stdafx.h

#pragma once
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
```

Interestingly, disabling the [Additional Security Checks (/sdl)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/sdl-enable-additional-security-checks?view=msvc-170) fixes the problem.

Both Release and Debug builds are affected with any Runtime Library setting: `/MT`, `/MTd`, `/MD`, `/MDd`.

The presence of Intel's Threading Building Blocks (TBB) header alone is enough to trigger this behavior - no linking to TBB is needed. TBB library was taken from the latest `vcpkg` at the time with the version `2021.10.0#3`.

Is it a bug in Visual Studio, or is it some incompatibility between TBB and Additional Security Checks?

Here is the assembly. Release configuration:

```
    std::vector<int> vs(foo() + 1);
00007FF79AF822C3  call        std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::_Xlength (07FF79AF81C70h)
```

Call to `foo()` is inlined and it throws immediately.

Debug configuration:

```
    std::vector<int> vs(foo() + 1);
00007FF7ACC743DD  mov         edx,20h  
00007FF7ACC743E2  lea         rcx,[vs]  
00007FF7ACC743E6  call        std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::__autoclassinit2 (07FF7ACC712E9h)  
00007FF7ACC743EB  lea         rcx,[rbp+104h]  
00007FF7ACC743F2  call        std::allocator<int>::allocator<int> (07FF7ACC714A1h)  
00007FF7ACC743F7  mov         qword ptr [rbp+138h],rax  
00007FF7ACC743FE  call        foo (07FF7ACC713D9h)  
00007FF7ACC74403  add         eax,1  
00007FF7ACC74406  mov         eax,eax  
00007FF7ACC74408  mov         rcx,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh  
00007FF7ACC7440F  cmovb       rax,rcx  
00007FF7ACC74413  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+138h]  
00007FF7ACC7441A  mov         r8,rcx  
00007FF7ACC7441D  mov         rdx,rax  
00007FF7ACC74420  lea         rcx,[vs]  
00007FF7ACC74424  call        std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::vector<int,std::allocator<int> > (07FF7ACC714F6h)
```

This piece is suspicious:

```
00007FF7ACC74408  mov         rcx,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh  
00007FF7ACC7440F  cmovb       rax,rcx
```

[The full solution is available on a GitHub](https://github.com/BG4444/TBB_MRE/tree/main)

Comment: Do you build the Release?

Comment: Any type of build is affected

Comment: Is that header only or is there a library being linked? If so does the library use the same runtime as your program? `/MT`, `/MTd` etc.

Comment: Library was not linked at all - the presence of the TBB header in PCH alone triggers the bug

Comment: Could you please try changing the Platform Toolset to the Intel C++ Compiler 2023 in the Visual Studio? We haven't observed this issue with the Intel oneAPI C++ Compiler. 
The Intel oneAPI C++ Compiler is available as part of the Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit and as a stand-alone product.
Please refer to the below link to download.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit-download.html